# Script for setting custom icon in Xcode for non-app MacOS bundle?

Tags: xcode, macos, icons, bundle

How can I set a custom icon (using a .icns file) during a script phase of an Xcode build targeting a non-app bundle?

We are making audio plug-ins, and would like to have our own icons instead of the default ones for our .vst3, .component, and .aaxplugin bundles.

I had some very old script that used to do this, but it relied on the old Rez utility and doing something I don't recall with a specific portion of the resource fork. Now, with bundles, I can't find the script I need to add to insert the icon and make it actually show up.

I have set the CFBundleIconFile string in the plist file to MyIcon.icns, and the script phase copies the MyIcon.icns file to the Contents/Resources folder, but it still does not show up in Finder with our icon. (If I change the plug-in extension to .app, our icon DOES show up, but then I can't change the bundle back to .vst3... it keeps the .app extension once that is set.)

Comment: I have no idea how you'd do this with just a script, but you can probably write yourself a simple command-line tool to do it using `-[NSWorkspace setIcon:forFile:options:]`. (I have a couple of custom build tools. Each is built by a target, the product that uses them depends on those build tool targets, and then the tools are run in the script phase of the product target.)